# Steps to move Magento CE 1.9.x to Magento 2.x?

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9

What are the potential steps to move from `Magento CE 1.9.x to Magento CE 2.x`
without any data loss or issues ?

Answer (score 1):

There are many links and documentation that you can use to get exact steps and problems that you will face during migration .

Magento 2 also have a tool that can help you to migrate  https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/migration/migration-tool-install.html

Basically you migration usually have steps like
**Theme Migration
Extension Migration
Customizations Migration
Data Migration**

you can find detailed info in
https://meetanshi.com/blog/migrate-from-magento-1-to-magento-2/
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/migration/migration-plan.html

I would like to suggest rather that moving to 2.1 , prefer moving to 2.3.5-p1 if not 2.4.1